# How can I get a full symmetric matrix from it's upper triangle in fortran

Tags: arrays, matrix, fortran, lapack, blas

I work with a symmetric matrix and only store its upper triangle (the lower triangle gets allocated but never initialized or touched). Now I need to add a vector to the first row of this matrix and subtract the same vector from the first column, making it a non-symmetric (general) matrix. For this purpose, I have to compute the whole symmetric matrix (replace the lower triangle with the transposed upper triangle). How can this be done in fortran using blas/lapack?

Comment: Please show your code so that the answerers do not have to write the whole code from scratch for you when you already have the basics and all the boilerplate. Did you try anything at all? However, it should be possible to compute the result without creating the whole symmetric matrix.

Comment: We need to see _how_ you have defined the triangular matrix structures.

Comment: Are you sure you add on the first row and substract one the first column, because the resulting matrix is not anymore symmetric, but if you doS ← S +  e₁.xᵀ+x.e₁ᵀ
  3 it remains symmetric and in this case identify the upper part of the matrix as the definition of the symetric matrix you co    uld do that with a base operationk